# Blackberry Simulator problem

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am using BB Java sdk 6.0.0.30 and I have installed BB 9780 Simulator Simpackage-6.0.0.285_9780 which I downloaded from BB site.

I installed this on net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.30\components\simulator,  after runnig an application I am facing the following problems

1 Not able to clean the simulator (I tried Project > Blackberry > Clean Simulator )

2 Not able to view Edited app on running, the app which is installed first time remains on the simulator after making some changes in code the new version is not getting loaded, but when I tried debugging the app with modified code is installed.

Any help is welcome

Regards,
A Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse plugin,
GO TO YOUR INSTALLATION PATH\plugins\YOUR COMPONANT PACK WHAT ARE YOU USING\components\simulator\,
RUN clean.bat;

Other idea just download again the installaer and install in a separated directory and copy the simulators from there  to your existing eclipse directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run clean.bat in C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.30\components\simulator\clean.bat. also close simulator before running it.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to clean the SIMULATOR you MUST close the simulator.

There is no need to clean SIMULATOR everytime. If you change your code then:

```
Rightclick on your project ------> refresh;
Rightclick on your project ------>BuildPoject;
Rightclick on your project ------> Debug As----->DebutCofiguration--->Debug;
```

If you have doubts come on StackOverFlow chat room name "**Life for Blackberry**" to clarify Your and our doubts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dhiral Pandya, I tried running clean.bat, I have installed a simulator that doesn't come with BB JDK 6.0; I have downloaded it seperately, when I run clea.bat file all information related to other simulator is also deleted

Answer (score 0):

Check  in eclipse  Project>Build Automatically is selected....
check your java version by typing java -version command in cmd it should be 1.6 ....
to set path for new jdk type : set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin im cmd

may be this information is useful for u.... best of luck

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dhiral Pandya, I tried running clean.bat, I have installed a simulator that doesn't come with BB JDK 6.0; I have downloaded it seperately, when I run clea.bat file all information related to other simulator is also deleted